# Nodejs Nested ForEach callback reciving Empty result

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to create a time table using this function when i try to console.log inside foreach it's responding correctly and print but when i try to send data as a callback parametr the function show me a empty result

```
    GetTimeTable(callback) {
    get_days = "SELECT * FROM days";
    var DayResponses = "";
    var TimeResponse = "";
    var day = 0;
    var time = 0;
    var table = "";
    var itemsProcessed = 0;
    connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM days', function (response_day) {
        response_day.forEach(Day => {
            DayResponses = Day;
            connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM time', function (response_time) {
                response_time.forEach(Time => {
                    TimeResponse = Time;
                    connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM time_table', function (response_time_table) {
                        response_time_table.forEach(time_table => {
                            table += DayResponses
                        })
                    }, 'SELECT')//Time   
                })
            }, 'SELECT')//Time
            itemsProcessed++;

            if (itemsProcessed == response_day.length) {

                callback(table);
            }

        });//Fore Day

    }, 'SELECT')//Days  
}
```

}

```
self.GetTimeTable(function (respones) {
console.log(respones)//Emty reuslt
```

});

Comment: You need to understand more about how callbacks work, your  inner`connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM time', function (response_time) {` callback function will be called after your main `callback(table)` function has been called as these are async operations. You should look at using async/await or Promise.all. In fact I've noticed you actually have 3 nested levels of callbacks which will need converting

Comment: Also, it's better to avoid `var` and consider using `const` and `let` to be sure in your variable scopes.

Answer (score 0):

yes i know this is bit late but if any one get this type of issue so i am giving my solution

```
GetTimeTabe(){
    new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM days', function (response_day) {
            if(response_day.length != null){//in here if the query whent wrong it's responding with a null and if there is no data it will send a empty array 
                resolve(response_day)
            }else{
                reject(response_day);
            }
        })
    }).then((data)=>{
        new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM time', function (response_time) {
                if(response_time.length != null){//in here if the query whent wrong it's responding with a null and if there is no data it will send a empty array 
                    resolve(response_time)
                }else{
                    reject(response_time);
                }
            })
        }).then((data)=>{
            new Promise((resolve,rejct)=>{
                data.forEach(Time => {
                    TimeResponse = Time;
                    connection.query(con, 'SELECT * FROM time_table', function (response_time_table) {
                        response_time_table.forEach(time_table => {
                            table += DayResponses
                        })
                    }, 'SELECT')//Time    
                    itemsProcessed++; 
            })
            if (itemsProcessed == response_day.length) {
    
                callback(table);
            }
            })
    })
    })
}
```

This is bit old code so and this code was the first code that i have used promises so bear with if there are better ways